# CSS Blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estou começando agora com Laravel 5.1, fiquei com uma dúvida com relação a blade.

Por exemplo, quero passar vários arquivos CSS ou JS da página em questão utilizando a notação da Blade. Meu arquivo principal está assim:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="@yield('css')" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>@yield('titulo')</title>
</head>
```

E na página assim:

```
@section('css', '/css/app.css')
```

Como eu posso fazer pra em uma determinada página carregar vários arquivos CSS? É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar isso de uma forma diferente, criando uma `@section` só para o CSS na sua página principal. É interessante colocar ali as *views* que todas as páginas irão utilizar:

```
// trecho do arquivo layouts/master.blade.php
@section('style')
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
@show
```

E nas views baseadas no `layouts/master`, você irá colocar as views específicas da pagina.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('style')
    @parent
    <link href="/css/app2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/app3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/app4.css" rel="stylesheet">        
@endsection
```

O `@parent` irá puxar o conteúdo da `@section` pai e colocar o conteúdo específico abaixo. Caso queira sobrescrever o conteúdo da `@section` basta não colocar o `@parent`

Comment: Não sei se ainda temos esse problema no `Laravel`, mas no `Laravel 3` esse parent aparecia na tela, caso não tivesse  nenhum "Filho"

Comment: No 5.1 não existe esse problema se fizer como indicado na resposta.

Comment: E na verdade é o contrario sua afirmação... o parent pode aparecer se a section não tiver um pai